# Installed Safari Extensions disappear after restarting Safari

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I have a problem with my Safari. I can not install any extensions. Whenever I install one they work fine, but the next time I open Safari, the extension is not there. So I have to reinstall them at every launch.

I have tried to clear my Safari stuff, like plists and Library folders. Im using Safari 8.0.1.

Comment: Do the installed extensions show up in `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/`?

Comment: Yes, @patrix...

Comment: What's Safari 8.0.1? I'm on OS X 10.10.1 and all I see is Safari 8.0...

Comment: @user24601 Developer Preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the login keychain locked or otherwise inaccessible? Apple now stores the list of installed Safari extensions in that keychain. See the link below for more details:

[Deploying & Installing Safari Extensions on Safari 6.1+ & 7.2+](https://macmule.com/2014/10/15/deploying-installing-safari-extensions-on-safari-6-1-7-2/)

Comment: Yes!! Thanks!! There was some permissions errors, so I deleted my login.keychain and now it works.

Comment: Thanks for this, this also solved my iMessages problem! Seems like Yosemite .1 messed up some things with the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "Safari 8.0.1" reveals that Apple wants developers to focus on "extension compatibility", meaning they probably screwed around with the way extensions are handled and ended up making this bug happen. I'd say finding a way to downgrade is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

try running disk utility and repairing permissions on that drive.

Comment: This is not a good answer, it should be a comment. I have already tried this.

Comment: i didn't have the ability to comments in original posts. it's helpful if you list what you've tried... try creating a new user account, opening safari and installing extensions.

Comment: Okay, no problem.